# react navigation drawer won't stay open

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

When I try to swipe it open, it swings right back.

I'm using stack with drawer together maybe this might be a problem, but so far
**I've tried everything**, reviewed all the similar questions to this but nothing worked

***my code***:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function DrawerNav({ navigation }) {
  // toggleDrawer = () => {
  //   this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())
  // }
  
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" 
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: brand,
        },
        headerTintColor: primary,
        headerTransparent: false,
        headerTitle: '',
        headerLeftContainerStyle: {
          paddingLeft: 20,
        },
    }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={horizontalAnimation}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStack = () => {

  return (
    <CredentialsContext.Consumer>
      {({ storedCredentials }) => (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: brand,
              },
              headerTintColor: primary,
              headerTransparent: true,
              headerTitle: '',
              headerLeftContainerStyle: {
                paddingLeft: 20,
              },
            }}
            
          >
            {storedCredentials ? (
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerNav} options={horizontalAnimation}/>
              
            ) : (
              <>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={horizontalAnimation}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} options={horizontalAnimation}/>
              </>
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
    </CredentialsContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I found out that some of my react-navigation libs where not on the same major release (in the package.json). So I changed them all to be on the same major version number, 6.X in my case, re-installed the packages and my code started working.

```
-    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.1",
-    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
-    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
+    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.4",
+    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.4",
+    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.9",
```

Comment: This worked for me - unsure why exactly.

Comment: They simply don't support (and probably don't test) mixed major version numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just change version of react-navigation/drawer if you have version 5

Comment: To what value? Where? Adding more detail will help future readers less familiar with the configuration and syntax, while also helping provide more specificity over when this issue was fixed.